# How to create an index to quickly find documents which do have and do not have a field defined?

Tags: mongodb

I have a 128 GB dataset stored in MongoDB. Some of the documents (initially all of them) are missing a particular field. This field is named `flag_sent_to_kafka`. You can guess what it does.

Because I created these documents before deciding that I wanted to send them to Kafka, the entire dataset initially is missing this field.

I could write a process to back-populate it, but I don't really want to do that because (I think) it forces me to turn off the process which is producing the documents until the whole dataset is updated. That will take a long time.

Instead, it seems like a better approach to just create an index which can be used to lookup documents which have the field `flag_sent_to_kafka` as well as those which do not have the field `flag_sent_to_kafka`.

I came up with this MongoSh command, but I am not convinced it is correct.

```
db.search_results_data.createIndex(
    {'flag_send_to_kafka': 1},
    {'partialFilterExpression': { 'flag_send_to_kafka': {$exists: true} }}
)
```

The [documentation pages show some examples](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-partial/). Here is one such example:

```
db.contacts.createIndex(
   { name: 1 },
   { partialFilterExpression: { email: { $exists: true } } }
)
```

The first argument is the `key`. In the example from the documentation pages the key does not match the key used in the `partialFilterExpression`. (`name` vs `email`)

This suggests to me that the command I have written does not do what I think it does.

This is what I want to achieve:

- Fast lookup of documents which **both have and do not have** the field `flag_sent_to_kafka`

**Edit:**

Having created this index, documents don't appear to be found more quickly. (The rate of processing documents has not increased.)

ChatGPT suggests I have the condition the wrong way round. In other words it should be `$exists: false` for fast lookup of documents which do not have this field.

However, I tried to create a second index for this and that did not work:

```
db.search_results_data.createIndex(
    {'flag_send_to_kafka': 1},
    {'partialFilterExpression': { 'flag_send_to_kafka': {$exists: false} }}
)
```

```
Error in specification. [...] Expression not supported in partial index: $not
`flag_send_to_kafka` exists
```

Comment: With that expression you are creating a partial index that must be met only when the specified criterion is true, so in your case only if it exists. You can simply remove that part and create an index for that field.

Comment: @MarcoRiccetti So a regular index will work regardless of whether the field exists in a document?

Comment: Yes exactly, by creating an index for that field you will allow MongoDB to index all documents that have that field but also it will indirectly index by difference those that do not have it i.e. when you run a query with $exists: false.

Comment: @MarcoRiccetti Ok great thanks, that was not at all obvious to me from the docs... What is the intended purpose of a partial index in this case? I'm now unsure as to why you would want to use a partial index instead of a full index.

Comment: I know it can be a little misleading but the simplest example I can think of is if you don't want to create a performance index but a constraint. Suppose, for example, you want to prevent a pair of values from uniquely existing but if and only if we are in a specific case. For example, in a hierarchy you might want to prohibit two children of the same parent from having the same name but only in some special cases namely those that match the partial filter expression.

Comment: @MarcoRiccetti add as an answer if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it as a regular index:

```
db.search_results_data.createIndex(
    { flag_send_to_kafka: 1 }
)
```

Creating a regular index for a field allows MongoDB to index all documents that have that field, and it indirectly indexes by difference those that do not have it. This can be achieved by running a query with `$exists: false`.

The intended purpose of a partial index is often to create a constraint rather than focusing solely on performance optimization. A common scenario is when you want to prevent certain pairs of values from uniquely existing, but only under specific conditions defined by the partial filter expression.

For example, consider the following case where you want to prohibit two children of the same parent from having the same name, but only in some special cases that match the partial filter expression.

```
db.tree.createIndex(
   // prohibit two children of the same parent from having the same name
   { parentId: 1, name: 1 },
   // but only if they have (for example) the unique flag enabled
   { partialFilterExpression: { uniqueFlag: true } }
)
```

So, while regular indexes cover all documents, partial indexes are useful when you want to impose constraints on a subset of documents based on specific conditions, ensuring that the index only includes documents that meet those criteria.